# Rake aborted! Don't know how to build task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I have a rake task in `semester.rake` file. It looks like this

```
namespace :db do
  desc "generate semester data"
  task semester: :environment do
    semester = Semester.create!(name: "SummerSemseter")
    semester = Semester.create!(name: "WinterSemester")
    semester = Semester.create!(name: "Spring Semester")        
  end
end
```

and I run the task as `rake semester`. This gives me error

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'semester' (see --tasks)
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why I get this error and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `semester` task is in a namespace `db`.

You need therefore to run it with:

```
rake db:semester
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Shadwell's answer your `semester` is in a namespace `db`.

so, **`rake db:semester`** will work for you

**You can know your rake tasks in your namespace using the command**

**`rake -T | grep namespace`**

**Eg:**

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  desc "TODO"
  task :my_task1 => :environment do
  end

  desc "TODO"
  task :my_task2 => :environment do
  end
end
```

**Gives,**

```
$ rake -T | grep my_namespace

rake my_namespace:my_task1  # TODO
rake my_namespace:my_task2  # TODO
```

So, if you run the command,

**`rake -T | grep db`** will give your rake taks under db namespace.

**`rake -T` command lists all rake taks available including yours**